# jmxterm: "Unable to create a system terminal" inside Docker container

Tags: docker, pty, jline

I have a Docker image which contains JRE, some Java web application and `jmxterm`. The latter is used for running some ad-hoc administrative tasks. The image is used on the CentOS 7 server with Docker 1.13 (which is pretty old but is the latest version which is supplied via the distro's repository) to run the web application itself.

All works well, but after updating `jmxterm` from 1.0.0 to the latest version (1.0.2), I get the following warning when entering the running container and starting `jmxterm`:

```
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
```

After this, `jmxterm` does not react to arrow keys (when trying to navigate through the command history), nor does it provide autocompletion.

Some quick investigation shows that the problem may be reproduced in the clean environment with CentOS 7. Say, this is how I could bootstrap the system and the container with all stuff I need:

```
$ vagrant init centos/7
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install docker
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start docker
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo docker run -it --entrypoint bash openjdk:11
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# wget https://github.com/jiaqi/jmxterm/releases/download/v1.0.2/jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar
```

And this is how I enter the container and run `jmxterm`:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo docker exec -it 0c4c614de0ee sh
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# bea<TAB>
<Nothing happens, but autocompletion had to appear>
```

Few observations:

- the problem does not appear with older `jmxterm` no matter which image do I use;
- the problem arises with new `jmxterm` no matter which image do I use;
- the problem is not reproducible on my laptop (which has newer kernel and Docker);
- the problem is not reproducible if I use latest Docker (from the external repo) on the CentOS 7 server instead of CentOS 7's native version 1.13.

What happens, and why the error is reproducible only in specific environments? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**: running new `jmxterm` versions as `java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar < /dev/tty` is a quick, dirty and hacky workaround for having the autocompletion and other stuff work inside the interactive container session.

---

A quick check shows that `jmxterm` tries to determine the terminal device used by the process — probably to obtain the terminal capabilities later — by running the `tty` utility:

```
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# strace -f -e 'trace=execve,wait4' java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar
execve("/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java", ["java", "-jar", "jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar"], 0x7ffed3a53210 /* 36 vars */) = 0
...
[pid   432] execve("/usr/bin/tty", ["tty"], 0x7fff8ea39608 /* 36 vars */) = 0
[pid   433] wait4(432, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 432
WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)
```

The utility fails with the status of 1, which is likely the reason for the error message. Why?

```
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# strace -y tty
...
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/3", 4095) = 10
stat("/dev/pts/3", 0x7ffe966f2160)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
write(1</dev/pts/3>, "not a tty\n", 10not a tty
) = 10
```

The utility says "not a tty" while we definitely have one. A quick check shows that... There is really *no PTY device in the container* though the standard streams of the shell are connected to one!

```
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:26 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:26 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:26 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------. 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:26 3 -> /proc/61/fd

root@0c4c614de0ee:/# ls -l /dev/pts
total 0
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 5, 2 Jun  3 21:26 ptmx
```

What if we check the same with latest Docker?

```
root@c0ebd608f79a:/# ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:45 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:45 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:45 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jun  3 21:45 3 -> /proc/16/fd

root@c0ebd608f79a:/# ls -l /dev/pts
total 0
crw--w---- 1 root tty  136, 0 Jun  3 21:44 0
crw--w---- 1 root tty  136, 1 Jun  3 21:45 1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5, 2 Jun  3 21:45 ptmx
```

Bingo! Now we have our PTYs where they should be, so `jmxterm` works well with latest Docker.

It seems pretty weird that with older Docker the processes are connected to some PTYs while there are no devices for them in `/dev/pts`, but tracing the Docker process explains why this happens. Older Docker allocates the PTY for the container *before* setting other things up (including entering the new mount namespace and mounting `devpts` into it or just entering the mount namespace in case of `docker exec -it`):

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo strace -p $(pidof docker-containerd-current) -f -e trace='execve,mount,unshare,openat,ioctl'
...
[pid  3885] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
[pid  3885] ioctl(9, TIOCGPTN, [1])     = 0
[pid  3885] ioctl(9, TIOCSPTLCK, [0])   = 0
...
[pid  3898] unshare(CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWNET|CLONE_NEWPID) = 0
...
[pid  3899] mount("devpts", "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3af250a9f118d637bfba5701f5b0dfc09ed154c6f9d0240ae12523bf252e350c/merged/dev/pts", "devpts", MS_NOSUID|MS_NOEXEC, "newinstance,ptmxmode=0666,mode=0"...) = 0
...
[pid  3899] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash"], 0xc4201626c0 /* 7 vars */ <unfinished ...>
```

Note the `newinstance` mount option which ensures that the `devpts` mount owns its PTYs exclusively and does not share them with other mounts. This leads to the interesting effect: the PTY device for the container stays on the host and belongs to the host's `devpts` mount, while the containerized process still has access to it, as it obtained the already-open file descriptors just in the beginning of its life!

The latest Docker first mounts `devpts` for the container and *then* allocates the PTY, so the PTY belongs to container's `devpts` mount and is visible inside the container's filesystem:

```
$ sudo strace -p $(pidof containerd) -f -e trace='execve,mount,unshare,openat,ioctl'
...
[pid 14043] unshare(CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWNET) = 0
...
[pid 14044] mount("devpts", "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b743cf16ab954b9a4b4005bca0aeaa019c4836c7d58d6073044e5b48446c3d62/merged/dev/pts", "devpts", 
MS_NOSUID|MS_NOEXEC, "newinstance,ptmxmode=0666,mode=0"...) = 0
...
[pid 14044] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
[pid 14044] ioctl(7, TIOCGPTN, [0])     = 0
[pid 14044] ioctl(7, TIOCSPTLCK, [0])   = 0
...
[pid 14044] execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"], 0xc000203530 /* 4 vars */ <unfinished ...>
```

Well, the problem is caused by inappropriate Docker behavior, but how comes that older `jmxterm` worked well in the same environment? Let's check (note, that Java 8 image is used here, as older `jmxterm` does not play well with Java 11):

```
root@504a7757e310:/# wget https://github.com/jiaqi/jmxterm/releases/download/v1.0.0/jmxterm-1.0.0-uber.jar
root@504a7757e310:/# strace -f -e 'trace=execve,wait4' java -jar jmxterm-1.0.0-uber.jar
execve("/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java", ["java", "-jar", "jmxterm-1.0.0-uber.jar"], 0x7fffdcaebdd0 /* 10 vars */) = 0
...
[pid   310] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "stty -a < /dev/tty"], 0x7fff1f2a1cc8 /* 10 vars */) = 0
```

So, older `jmxterm` just uses `/dev/tty` instead of asking `tty` for the device name, and this works, as this device is present inside the container:

```
root@504a7757e310:/# ls -l /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 5, 0 Jun  3 21:36 /dev/tty
```

The huge difference between these versions of `jmxterm` is that newer tool version uses higher major version of `jline`, which is the library responsible for interaction with the terminal (akin to the `readline` in the C world). The difference between major `jline` versions leads to the difference in `jmxterm`'s behavior, and current versions [just rely on `tty`](https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/9739190986d6ea38ed1c12f2af09c564049e9306/terminal/src/main/java/org/jline/terminal/impl/ExecPty.java#L39-L46).

This observation leads us to the quick and dirty workaround which does not require neither updating Docker nor patching the `jline`/`jmxterm` tandem: we may just attach `jmxterm`'s stdin to `/dev/tty` forcibly and thus make `jline` use this device (which is now referenced by `/proc/self/fd/0`) instead of the `/dev/pts` entry (which, formally, is not always correct, but is still enough for ad-hoc use):

```
root@0c4c614de0ee:/# java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar < /dev/tty
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
$>bea<TAB>
bean    beans
```

Now we have the autocompletion, history and other cool things we need to have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run an interactive application (that needs tty) inside a docker container or a pod in kubernetes, then the following should work.

For docker-compose use:

```
image: image-name:2.0
container_name: container-name
restart: always

stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

For kubernetes use:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: web:latest

        tty: true
        stdin: true
```